# getting angle with known coordinates

Tags: python, trigonometry

I have an object on my canvas and I want to make an arrow pointing on it. I already have an image of arrow, that is pointing up, and I need to know the angle I must rotate it by to make it point on that image. The arrow is always at position (0, 0), but the position of the second picture can change.
[image]

I know I can count sine and cosine of that angle, but it's not the thing I'm looking for, It must be exactly that angle.

Comment: Any code examples?

Comment: Well, I didn't know what to put there as I have no Idea how to do it

Comment: The angle is `90 - arctan(Y/X)`.  You probably want to use `math.atan2(y,x)`, and remember that returns radians, not degrees. If you want degrees, it's `90 - math.atan2(y,x) * 180 / math.pi`.

Comment: It works! You were really helpful

Comment: Can you turn it into an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The angle is `90 - arctan(Y/X)`. You probably want to use `math.atan2(y,x)`, and remember that returns radians, not degrees. If you want degrees, it's

```
angle = 90 - math.atan2(y,x) * 180 / math.pi
```